# "Model estimation FAILED! Returning starting values": SEM with missing data

Tags: missing-data, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, error-message

I am using R (4.1.3) with lavaan to run a longitudinal SEM with the American National Election Studies 2016-2020 Panel Data. It's a simple model: Time 2 outcome (2 indicators) predicted by Time 1 outcome (2 indicators) and three correlated X variables (1 indicator each). The error variances of the 1-indicator latent variables are fixed. There should be at least 1 df. Total sample size is 2839 (1855 excluding missing).

My syntax is below:

```
anes1620use<- anes1620[c("V202377", "V162192", "V201255", "V161189", "V161126", "V162244", "V161137")]

library(nainar)
anes1620use<- anes1620use %>% replace_with_na(replace = list(V202377 = c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99), V162192= c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99), V201255= c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99), V161189= c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99) , V161126= c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99), V162244= c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99), V161137= c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,0,99)))

model<-'
YT2=~V202377+V201255
YT1=~V162192+V161189

X1=~V161126
X2=~V162244
X3=~V161137

YT2~YT1+X1+X2+X3

V202377~~V202377
V201255~~V201255
V162192~~V162192
V161189~~V161189

V161126~~0*V161126
V162244~~0*V162244
V161137~~0*V161137

YT1~~0*X1
YT1~~0*X2
YT1~~0*X3
'
fit <- lavaan(model, data = anes1620use, estimator = "MLR")
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

The error that returns is

> "In lavaan(model, data = anes1620use, estimator = "MLR") : lavaan
> WARNING:
> Model estimation FAILED! Returning starting values."

I have gotten this model to run with simulated data...any tips for where I'm going wrong?

Edit: Here is the code with simulated data

```
library(faux)

provo <- rnorm_multi(n = 200, 
                  mu = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  sd = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  r = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
            0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5,
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1),
                  varnames = c("x1t1", "x2t1", "x3t1", "x1t2", "x2t2", "x3t2", "y1t1", "y1t2", "y2t1", "y2t2"),
                  empirical = FALSE)


newmodel3<-'
#regression
fyt2~fyt1+fx1t1+fx2t1+fx3t1

#latent variable definitions

fyt1=~y1t1+y2t1
fyt2=~y1t2+y2t2
fx1t1=~x1t1
fx2t1=~x2t1
fx3t1=~x3t1

#variances

x1t1~~0.3504348*x1t1
x2t1~~0.4810297*x2t1
x3t1~~0.5725228*x3t1

y1t1~~y1t1
y1t2~~y1t2
y2t1~~y2t1
y2t2~~y2t2

#covariances

fyt1~~0*fx1t1
fyt1~~0*fx2t1
fyt1~~0*fx3t1
'
fit<-sem(newmodel3, data=provo)
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

There are negative variances (I wasn't surpised given the data), however the model at least runs

If it is helpful, when I wrong the code for the ANES data, I also get this error message

```
> summary(fit, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)
lavaan 0.6-11 did not run (perhaps do.fit = FALSE)?
** WARNING ** Estimates below are simply the starting values
```

I'm not familiar with this error, though I did read briefly that it is related to not having data. Is anyone more knowledgeable about what could cause this error?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to simulate the data?

Comment: Sure thing. Added!